# Cannot understand syntax of recordset.FindFirst function

Tags: ms-access, vba

After hours of research I still cannot understand what is wrong with my syntax.

```
rs.FindFirst "[Date] =" & Date() & " AND [Employee] = " & [Forms]![Machinist Timesheet]![Frame4]
```

It just gives me a runtime error on my syntax.

Many solutions involve a lot of delimiting apostrophes or quotation marks but I don't understand why they are necessary.

Comment: Try rs.FindFirst "[Date] =#" & Date() & "# AND ...

Comment: Always provide the runtime error number and description. It always helps.

Comment: Sorry it was a typo, there was an ampersand there. Fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **FindFirst** method is essentially asking for the "WHERE" part of a SQL query without the "WHERE".

Fields in databases are certain datatypes and must be expressed as such in SQL.

- **Dates:** #1/31/2015#
- **Strings:** 'single quotes' -- or -- "double quotes"
- **Numbers:** 4, 5.5, 7 / 8  (no markup necessary)
- **Fields:** [FieldName]

Try writing your code like this:

```
rs.FindFirst "[Date] = #" & Format(Date(), "m/d/yyyy") & "# AND [Employee] = " _
    & [Forms]![Machinist Timesheet]![Frame4]
```

This will use a criteria SQL fragment like so:

```
[Date] = #7/31/2015# AND [Employee] = 5
```

If the Employee field is not a number, it should have quotes, like so:

```
rs.FindFirst "[Date] = #" & Format(Date(), "m/d/yyyy") & "# AND [Employee] = '" _
    & [Forms]![Machinist Timesheet]![Frame4] & "'"
```

For a criteria SQL fragment:

```
[Date] = #7/31/2015# AND [Employee] = '698-48-1247'
```

You may want to write your routine like this and then check the value of sCriteria so that it is correctly formatted. If you are not sure it is correctly formatted, copy it and paste it into a query in SQL view after "WHERE"

```
Dim sCriteria As String

sCriteria = "[Date] = #" & Format(Date(), "m/d/yyyy") & "# AND [Employee] = " & _
    [Forms]![Machinist Timesheet]![Frame4]

Debug.Print sCriteria

rs.FindFirst sCriteria
```

**References**

- [VBA RecordSet.FindFirst](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/Ff194787.aspx)
- [Access WHERE Clause](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Bb221200(v=office.12).aspx)

Comment: Do you not need to `Format` the result of the `Date()` function?

Comment: That's a good idea if it will run in locations where the default is not m/d/yyyy. Updated my answer.